# How can I get the model of a RichTable?

Tags: oracle-adf

I have a ADF `RichTable`. The model is a `List<CustomThresholdRow>`. I am not using ADF BC layer. I have two buttons say *Add* and *Delete* on click of which I want to add/delete a row respectively.

I think I will be done implementing this feature if I have an API which will give the whole model of the table(`getWrappedData()`). But I do not find this method on the `RichTable` class. I am looking for something like the following:

```
List<CustomThresholdRow> allRows = (List<CustomThresholdRow>)getWrappedData();
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
DataModel tableModel = (CollectionModel)richTable.getValue();
List<CustomThresholdRow> dataList = 
                  (List<CustomThresholdRow>)tableModel.getWrappedData()
```

Comment: He is not using ADF BC, so the return from richTable.getValue() won't be a CollectionModel!

Answer (score 0):

If you access your java list through data controls, you should have basic CRUD operations available, which can be dragged in from the data controls view.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
List<CustomThresholdRow> allRows = (List<CustomThresholdRow>)adfRichTableInstance.getValue();
```